# Environment.OSVersion.get is deprecated

Tags: c#

when I use `public static readonly string OsType = Environment.OSVersion.VersionString;` in my code, I'll get a warning about like follows:

```
 warning DE0009: Environment.OSVersion.get is deprecated [C:\projects\projectSource\WeihanLi.Common\src\WeihanLi.Common\WeihanLi.Common.csproj]
```

what api should I use for instead?

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> The Environment.OSVersion property does not provide a reliable way to identify the exact operating system and its version. Therefore, we do not recommend that you use this method. Instead:
>
> To identify the operating system platform, use the RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform method.
>
> Avoid writing code that depends on a reported operating system version. Instead, check for the availability of the features that your application needs.